# Installing multiple variations of the app on one device

Tags: java, android, gradle

Gradle Problem for insatll Debug Apk

[image: IDE screenshot]

This Android demo has free,paid,pro productflavors ,and debug,release buildtypes.
all the flavors folders have java source code files and res files
when run gradlew instaDebFl to install Debug Apk on the device.
the terminal tells me "task with path 'installFreeDebug' not found in project ':app'
How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in your gradle file line 302. `insatll`

Comment: yay! I didn't see it ,thanks. If free and paid have same Activity , but the AndroidManifest.xml  in main folder only register the free flavor Activity ,when build paid flavor apk, cause an error that not found free.Activity , how can i fix it ?

Comment: By deleting this question (typo questions are off-topic on SO) and then posting a new detailed question instead of asking another question in a comment. ;-)